# How to setJavascriptEnabled in selenium-junit4-runner

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In selenium-junit4-runner I tried setting the following in my test:

webDriver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

but it says method is undefined for WebDriver.

How do I set it?

Comment: Typo?  webDriver ≠ WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver is an **interface**, all 'real' browsers implementations like *FirefoxDriver*, *InternetExplorerDriver*, *ChromeDriver* have the javaScript enabled by default, so there is nothing you need to enable :)

The only implementation the required special handling with JavaScript is the [HtmlUnitDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver).

You can enable Javascript either through the constructor:

```
// Create a new instance of the HtmlUnitDriver
// Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
// not the implementation.
     WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver (true);
```

or

```
   //less recommended, working with implemetation only   
  HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();  
  driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```